# Which Self registration apex controller is used for experience builder page register

Tags: community, experience-builder-page, self-registration

I have my experience site set up for self registration and I need to tweak the Registration Controller to match on existing contacts if present. The issue is I cannot figure out which controller is tied to the below registration page:

[image]

There seems to be three existing controllers that could all be the one, but None seem to do anything when I change them.

LightningSelfRegisterController:

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static String selfRegister(String firstname ,String lastname, String email, String password, String confirmPassword, String accountId, String regConfirmUrl, String extraFields, String startUrl, Boolean includePassword) {
    Savepoint sp = null;
    try {
        sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        
        if (lastname == null || String.isEmpty(lastname)) {
            return Label.Site.lastname_is_required;
        }
        
        if (email == null || String.isEmpty(email)) {
            return Label.Site.email_is_required;
        }
        
        System.Debug('In Communities Self Reg Controller v1');
        List<Contact> existingContact = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = :email];
        String contactId = null;
        if(existingContact.size() > 0){
            System.Debug(existingContact.size());
            contactId = existingContact[0].Id;
            accountId = existingContact[0].AccountId;
        }
        
        User u = new User();
        u.Username = email;
        u.put('Email',email);
        if(contactId != null){
            u.contactId = contactId;
        }
        u.FirstName = firstname;
        u.LastName = lastname;
        
        String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();
        
        // If using site to host the community the user should not hit s1 after logging in from mobile.
        if(networkId != null && siteAsContainerEnabled(Network.getLoginUrl(networkId))) {
            u.put('UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI',true);
        }
        
        String nickname = ((firstname != null && firstname.length() > 0) ? firstname.substring(0,1) : '' ) + lastname.substring(0,1);
        nickname += String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger()).substring(1,7);
        u.put('CommunityNickname', nickname);
        
        if (extraFields != null) {
            List<Object> extraFieldsList = (List<Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(extraFields);        
            for (Object thisFieldObject : extraFieldsList) {
                Map<String,Object> thisField = (Map<String,Object>) thisFieldObject;
                Schema.SObjectField sof = Schema.SObjectType.User.fields.getMap().get((String) thisField.get('fieldPath'));
                u.put(sof, thisField.get('value'));
            }
        }
        
        if (includePassword) {    
            if (!isValidPassword(password, confirmPassword)) {
                return Label.site.passwords_dont_match;
            }
            validatePassword(u, password, confirmPassword);
        }
        else {
            password = null;
        }
        
        // lastName is a required field on user, but if it isn't specified, we'll default it to the username
        String userId = Site.createPortalUser(u, accountId, password);
        // create a fake userId for test.
        if (Test.isRunningTest()) {
            userId = 'fakeUserId';           
        }
        if (userId != null) { 
            if (password != null && password.length() > 1) {
                ApexPages.PageReference lgn = Site.login(email, password, startUrl);
                if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    aura.redirect(lgn);
                }
            }
            else {
                ApexPages.PageReference confirmRef = new PageReference(regConfirmUrl);
                if(!Test.isRunningTest()) {
                    aura.redirect(confirmRef);
                }
                
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        Database.rollback(sp);
        return ex.getMessage();            
    }
}
```

SiteRegisterController

```
    public PageReference registerUser() {
    // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
    if (!isValidPassword()) {
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        return null;
    }
    String accountId = PORTAL_ACCOUNT_ID;
    String contactId = null;
            System.Debug('In Site Self Reg Controller');
    List<Contact> existingContact = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = :email];
    if(existingContact.size() > 0){
        System.Debug(existingContact.size());
        contactId = existingContact[0].Id;
        accountId = existingContact[0].AccountId;
    }
    User u = new User();
    u.Username = username;
    u.Email = email;
    u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
     if(contactId != null){
        u.ContactId = contactId;
    }
```

CommunitiesSelfRegController

```
    public PageReference registerUser() {

       // it's okay if password is null - we'll send the user a random password in that case
    if (!isValidPassword()) {
        ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, Label.site.passwords_dont_match);
        ApexPages.addMessage(msg);
        return null;
    }    

    String profileId = null; // To be filled in by customer.
    String roleEnum = null; // To be filled in by customer.
    String accountId = ''; // To be filled in by customer.
    String contactId = null;
    String userName = email;
    System.Debug('In Communities Self Reg Controller');
    List<Contact> existingContact = [SELECT Id, AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Email = :email];
    if(existingContact.size() > 0){
        System.Debug(existingContact.size());
        contactId = existingContact[0].Id;
        accountId = existingContact[0].AccountId;
    }
   

    User u = new User();
    u.Username = userName;
    u.Email = email;
    u.FirstName = firstName;
    u.LastName = lastName;
    u.CommunityNickname = communityNickname;
    u.ProfileId = profileId;
    if(contactId != null){
        u.ContactId = contactId;
    }
    System.Debug('User ContactID: ' + u.contactId);
    System.Debug('ContactID: ' + contactId);
    
    String userId;
```

In all of the above, I added a query for existing contact and attempt to pass it in to the user creation code. None of them seem to work so im wondering which, if any, is actually the one controlling my self registration.

Comment: It should be the CommunitiesSelfRegController. Take a look at the documentation here: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_self_reg_apex.htm&type=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one you need to edit is the `CommunitiesSelfRegController` according to the documentation here: [Customize the Self-Registration Apex Controller](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_self_reg_apex.htm&type=5). It's important to note that you'll need to provide access to the controller to your guest user profile following the steps in that article.

This overrides the settings that you define in the Login & Registration page settings.

Comment: Is that going to switch our self registration component to the visualforce version?

Comment: If you want to customise the behaviour, then yes you'll need to or build a completely custom Lightning Component for managing this behaviour.